# Optional dependencies in distutils / pip

Tags: python, distutils, pip

When installing my python package, I want to be able to tell the user about various optional dependencies. Ideally I would also like to print out a message about these optional requirements and what each of them do.

I haven't seen anything yet in the docs of either pip or docutils. Do tools these support optional dependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664478/optional-dependencies-in-a-pip-requirements-file

Comment: If they're optional, they're not strictly dependencies, are they?

Comment: I call them optional dependencies, because that is what ubuntu's package manager call them. They are not strictly required, but if they are installed, the program can use them.

Comment: Not a duplicate of 3664478, the other asker explicitly wanted pip-requirements which isn't a very natural way to handle this.

Answer (score 57):

These are called extras, [here is how to use them in your setup.py, setup.cfg, or pyproject.toml](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies).

The base support is in pkg_resources. You need to enable distribute in your `setup.py`. pip will also understand them:

```
pip install 'package[extras]'
```

Comment: Is there a standardised way to view which extras are available?

Comment: @Sean1708 No, pip doesn't have a feature like that today.  One workaround is to inspect the source code's `setup.py` file for extras. 
 Another is to check the "extras" key in the installed package's `<package name>-<version>.dist-info/metadata.json` inside `site-packages` (or wherever you have the package installed).

Comment: Updated documentation link: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies

Comment: For anyone else who ends up here because of 'no matches found' when trying to install an optional dependency, it only worked for me once I added the quotes seen in this answer.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, at stated by @Tobu and explained [here](https://creatronix.de/pip-optional-dependencies/). In your `setup.py` file you can add a line like this:

```
extras_require = {
        'full': ['matplotlib', 'tensorflow', 'numpy', 'tikzplotlib']
    }
```

I have an example of this line [here](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn/blob/d50acd4d7ea8bc0d2f85a707d757f41d44598d25/setup.py#L36).

Now you can either install via PIP basic/vanilla package like `pip install package_name` or the package with all the optional dependencies like `pip install package_name[full]`

Where `package_name` is the name of your package and `full` is because we put "full" in the `extras_require` dictionary but it depends on what you put as a name.

---

If someone is interested in how to code a library that can work with or without a package I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051266/5931672)

Answer (score 14):

Since PEP-621, this information is better placed in the pyproject.toml rather than setup.py.  Here's the relevant specification from [PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/#dependencies-optional-dependencies). Here's an example snippet from a pyproject.toml (credit to @GwynBleidD):

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
  "pytest < 5.0.0",
  "pytest-cov[all]"
]
lint = [
  "black",
  "flake8"
]
ci = [
  "pytest < 5.0.0",
  "pytest-cov[all]",
  "black",
  "flake8"
]
```

A more complete [example](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/#example) is found in the PEP

Comment: You can then install them with e.g. `pip install .[test]` or `pip install your_package[lint]`