# Should I split my python module into multiple packages?

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am currently developing a python module, say `my_package`, which contains some image processing algorithms. It contains a `setup.py` for a convenient installation. Now I want to add a gui to the package so that users can try the algorithms and play with parameters. The gui will use Qt from the `PySide2` package. Are there best practices for the package / directory structure for modules with both algorithms and gui?

At first I wanted to create submodules `my_package.core` and `my_package.gui`. However, since users can only install `my_package` as a whole, this will add the `PySide2` dependency to all users, even if they just want to use the algorithms without the gui. Is it better if I create two separate packages `my_package` and `my_package_gui`, both with their own `setup.py`? Or will this be confusing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional dependencies in distutils / pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237946/optional-dependencies-in-distutils-pip)

Comment: Yes that may be a good solution. In my case, does this mean that users may choose between `pip install my_package`, which just installs the algorithms, and `pip install "my_package[gui]"`, which also installs `PySide2` and a GUI script?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. cf the doc here https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies for more details.

Comment: Now you can of course also have two totally distinct packages for the core and  the gui and make the core a dependency of the gui. At this point which solution is "best" is mostly a matter of context, opinions and personal tastes ;-)

Comment: Well, that's kind of the point of my question :) Which one is a better practice? Two distinct packages or a single package with optional dependency? Do pip users know about optional dependencies? I have been using it for quite a while and this is the first time I heard about them.

Comment: I'm afraid that " Which one is a better practice" falls under the "primarily opinion based" category ;-)

Comment: wrt/ "pip users (knowing about) extra features", it's your responsability as the package maintainer to clearly document it in the readme / package description / documentation. And you'll have the same issue with two distinct packages actually (you'll need to document the existence of the "gui" package in the "core" one else your users won't know there's a gui too). IOW it doesn't really make a difference...