# Can I combine pip installation based on requirements.txt with optional extra packages PEP508?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

For some while, I have been looking for a method to use a `requirements.txt` file (see [format specification](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/)) with optional package extras depending on the use case, e.g., for testing purposes:

```
# requirements.txt
pandas >= 2
pytest [test] >= 7
pytest-testdox [test]
```

I follow the standard definition in [PEP 508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#extras) for defining and grouping these optional extras.

I would like to use a command like the following one, which does not work:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt[test]
```

Ideally, there would be a flag for specifying the extras involved but there is none as far as I know.

### Workaround

I was writing in the end a `pyproject.toml`, which allows the following workaround as proposed in [the official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/):

```
pip install '.[test]'
```

This command runs successfully based on the following (probably minimal) file:

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["myproject"]

[project]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.1"
dependencies = [
    "pandas",
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest >= 7",
    "pytest-testdox",
]
```

This approach, however, builds a new unnecessary package `myproject` out of the given file and folder, which I want to avoid.

Comment: `pytest [test] >= 7` does not put `pytest` into a `test` extras group in your project; it specifies you want the `test` extra when installing `pytest`, but: `pytest 7.4.3 does not provide the extra 'test'`...

Comment: `requirements.txt` is fixed in stone (well, in text file); there're no ways to pass parameters to it. If you need to install different groups  you create different `requirements.txt` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring your extras in `pyproject.toml` is the modern way to go.

Simply install your project as [editable with `-e`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html), and it won't be separately built.

```
pip install -e '.[test]'
```

If you do want to use `requirements.txt` style files and you're using recent versions of `setuptools` as your build backend, you should be able to specify those files as [dynamic metadata sources](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata).

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the configuration via `pyproject.toml` is the way to proceed although I am not writing a Python package for reuse but just project code for data analysis etc.!

Comment: Well, the file does have _project_ in the name too...  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the extra specifier is not to control which packages in the `requirements.txt` to be installed. Instead, it is used to mark the optional dependencies of installed packages. For example, if you specify `pytest[test]` in your `requirements.txt`, you will install the extra packages which are used for testing the `pytest` package.

As far as I know, it's not quite possible to pass parameters to the `pip install -r` command. An alternative way to achieve this is to create multiple `requirement.txt` files, or control it with packaging utilities (`setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`, etc.).

See also: [Optional dependencies in distutils / pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237946/optional-dependencies-in-distutils-pip)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I think I misunderstood the notation for writing a `requirements.txt` file.