# How to install dependencies with square brackets in python setup.py?

Tags: python, ray

I am trying to include the `ray` into my own package. However, there are some dependencies needed for using ray that should be installed via `pip install ray[all]`.

If I just add `ray[all]` into the `install_requires` of `setup.py`, like:

```py
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        ...
        "ray==1.0.0",
        "ray[all]==1.0.0",
    ]
)
```

Then running `pip install -e .` can not install the dependencies specified in `ray[all]`. However, I wish my user can install everything simply via running `pip install -e .`.

Can anyone provide a solution for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490897/how-to-install-python-module-extras-with-pip-requirements-txt-file) answers your question.

Comment: Just asking for information ..is `[all]` even an option? Also, wouldn't `requirements.txt` be better?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install -e .[all]`.

In general `pip install -e .[extras]` should work for all python packages that are packaged with setuptools.

Comment: `[]` are shell metacharacters.  You'd probably have to put that part in quotes to protect them.  Or is that the purpose of the leading `.`?

Comment: quotes might make sense: `pip install -e '.[all]'`

Comment: The purpose of the `.` is to specify the root directory of the method. When I tested this on my bash shell, this worked without quotes, though the quotes shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Ah ha!  If you have file(s) named a, b, or c, then the shell will expand `[abc]` to those filenames; otherwise the shell passes a literal `[abc]` to the command.  You must not have had any files named e, x, t, r, a, or s.